# Hibernate 4.3.6 + spring - recursive delete method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have spring project with hibernate. When I try to delete object in this way:

```
     User ent = userDaoImpl.load(User.class, 1); 
     userDaoImpl.delete(ent);
```

The result is following:

```
     root cause
  java.lang.StackOverflowError
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
com.maxim.spring.dao.UserDaoImpl.delete(UserDaoImpl.java:50)
 ...
```

I read that object should be in persistent context, so it is loaded by load method.
In advance to the questions, interface implementation works in the following way:

```
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    delete(user);

}


@Override 
public User load(Class cl, int id){
    return (User) getSession().getCurrentSession().load(cl, id);
}
```

And implementation extends AbstractDao too.

AbstractDao method:

```
public void delete(Object entity) {
     getSession().getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
}
```

How to make it in the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method

```
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    delete(user);

}
```

will keep calling itself till you have a memory on the stack.
You should change it to

```
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    getSession().getCurrentSession().delete(user);
}
```

Or just remove it and use `delete` method from `AbstractDao`.

Answer (score 0):

If the method in the abstract class does the job, just don't override it.

Alternatively you could

```
@Override
public void delete(User user) {
    super.delete(user);
}
```

But that's unnecessary.